# Report and Edit Post Link

Tags: contact

I want to give Link "Report / Edit Post" on every wordpress post, so visitor can click on that link and submit "Name, Email, Phone, Text" and admin can receive above details along with website url.
How to do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea, you can do multiple things:

1. **Use a form builder plugin like Gravity with some customization:** You can create a link for every post with the id of the post in the parameters of URL. The link must be the link of the page that you created your gravity form in it with your desired fields. You should also do some code customization in the form page to assign the field for just this post. This can be a hidden field that get the id from the url.
2. **Create your own form:** This will need more coding. First, you should create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). This page template will contain your form codes. In the next step you should add the "Report / Edit Post" automatically in the bottom of the post. You can do this by using [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter. Don't forget to add the post id to the parameters of the URL. This must be linked to your form page. In that page you can do processing of the form. For storing the data, you can create a custom table which saves the name, email, phone, text, website URL and also the post id.

Also this is a bit tricky, but you should not ask such a wide question. I can give a the codes but first you should start to writing it and ask about more precise problems.